# Postgresql Sequence not increase by 1

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I use a sequence in the PostgreSQL table with an 8-digits start number like:

```
20000101
20000102
```

And execute INSERT query with SQLAlchemy ORM in API (AWS lambda) like:

```
result = session.query("select nextval('mydb.student_id_seq')").one_or_none()
id = result[0]

student_model = Student(
    id=id,
    name="Name",
    class_id="Class ID",
    grade="A"
)
```

But sometimes a sequence number increases by a random number or roll-back to the previous number like:

```
20000200
20000201
20000202
20000214
20000215
20000221
20000222
```

How can I solve this problem?

I want to know How to use the PostgreSQL Sequence in SQLAlchemy correctly.

Comment: It's because of [sequence caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html). The client you use can request and reserve next N numbers from the sequence, then [`discard` the ones it didn't use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html). Someone else can get those returns later, or have to use numbers above what's already reserved by others.

Comment: @Zegarek Thanks for your reply! I set the cache value to 1 (no cache) but does it have an effect?

Comment: The setting dictates how many can be reserved, cached. It doesn't stop anyone from depleting the sequence by requesting numbers from it and discarding them.

Comment: @Zegarek Additional, Will this problem solve if I add 'session.close()' after insert?

Comment: If you disable session-level sequence cache by limiting it to 1, some ORMs can still try and emulate caching/prefetching sequence numbers on their own. `Session.close()` won't help much if it's an asynchronous application. I'd recommend relying on autoincremented ID instead of trying to handle it on your own and wrestle with a system meant to handle things for you. Also, *why* do you want the gapless ID?

Comment: @Zegarek I use 'id' as the order of registration. Before applying the sequence, I inserted a number last id + 1 manually. But as the number of concurrent users increased, so 'id' was changed to sequence type. I understand your answer correctly. I'll change to auto-increment id. Thanks for your detailed explanation! :)

Comment: numbers don't rollback, a sequence never ever rolls back, not even in a transaction that failed. Unless you give it a new number to start with.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Apart from cycling back, being asked to roll back with `setval()`, designed or altered to increment by negative, they can also appear to roll back - last of which is what I think OP refers to. A session fetches a `nextval()` first, waits for someone else to insert the next `nextval()` and then inserts the value it held, making it look like the sequence first skipped a number, then changed direction and went back to it. With chains of events that end up issuing commits in a LIFO it could be especially amusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of [sequence caching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html). The client you use can request and reserve next N numbers from the sequence, then [`discard` the ones it didn't use](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-discard.html). Someone else can get those returns later, or have to use numbers above what's already reserved by others.

Don't rely on the continuity of `nextval()` from a non-temp sequence you don't own/use exclusively and can't lock. From the doc linked above:

> Because `nextval` and `setval` calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.
>
> Unexpected results might be obtained if a *`cache`* setting greater than one is used for a sequence object that will be used concurrently by multiple sessions. Each session will allocate and cache successive sequence values during one access to the sequence object and increase the sequence object's `last_value` accordingly. Then, the next *`cache`*-1 uses of `nextval` within that session simply return the preallocated values without touching the sequence object. So, any numbers allocated but not used within a session will be lost when that session ends, resulting in “holes” in the sequence.
>
> Furthermore, although multiple sessions are guaranteed to allocate distinct sequence values, the values might be generated out of sequence when all the sessions are considered.

You don't need to manually handle the id sequence in your model and guard it. Make the field use an [integer generated as identity](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#identity-ddl).